# Sscanf or Strtok file parsing in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have to read numerous lines of plain text data from different files, in these tree types of format:

```
    Variable:Value  //Format 1
    Variable2:Value   
    .... //Numerous lines of any of the three formats
    Variable0 Variable1 Variable2:Value //Format 2
    ...
    STATIC*:a b c d //Format 3
```

Format 1 seems trivial, but may be pointless in handling separately due to format 2, because format 2 can have any length of variables before the colon. Essentially format 1 is just a case where format2 has only one variable.

Format 2 in it's smallest form will look like Format 1. Format 2 can have any number of text "variables" before the final variable/value pair.
In the example above, Variable0 would ideally point to Variable1 which would point to Variable2 and its value:Value

Format 3 will have a static string, with an identifier after that static string (denoted by the *). Followed by four integer values.

---

I have hundreds of files containing data in these three formats. I'm trying to currently figure out how to read the data efficiently in C (because I was asked to use C).

Strtok seems to fail me because if I simply delimit each line by white space, format 2 would cause problems.

Sscanf seems slightly more ideal, because I can specify some type of format which could help with both formats 1 and 3, but still seems to fall short in helping me with 2.

Is it even possible to make one of these work for all three? If not, what would be a more ideal function that I may have overlooked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line.

You have the colon. Look for that,set it to zero and  set a pointer to the next character, that is is always value. Then step backwards from that till you get to either the line start or a space..

so

```
char *value, *variable;

value=strchr(line ':'); // find the colon
variable=value; // set variable to where end of variable is
*value++='\0'; // replace colon with a null and step value past it
while(variable>line && *(variable-1) !=' ') // step backward until start of line or a space
    variable--;

/* now `variable` points to the last bit of the line
before the colon, and `value` points to the first bit 
of line after the colon, and both are properly null terminated. */
```

and then do what you want with the fragments...

If its the asterisk case, check the final character of `variable`

```
int var1, var2, var3, var4;
    if(variable[strlen(variable-1)]=='*')
        sscanf(value, "%d %d %d %d", &var1, &var2, & var3, &var4);
    else var1=atoi(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have a line of text.

Algorithm for parsing variables:

```
char* variables = strtok(line, ":");
char* value = strtok(NULL, " ");
char* variable = strtok(variable, " ");
while ( variable != NULL )
{
   // Do something with the variable.
   ...
   // Get the next variable
   variable = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Algorithm for parsing:

```
char* staticString = strtok(line, ":");
char* values = strtok(NULL, " ");
char* value = strtok(values, " ");
while ( value != NULL )
{
   // Do something with the value
   ...
   // Get the next value
   value = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

**Example Program That Echoes The Input**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function to parse the "Variable:value" lines.
void parseLine1(char* line)
{
   char* variables = strtok(line, ":");
   char* value = strtok(NULL, " ");
   char* variable = strtok(variables, " ");
   while ( variable != NULL )
   {
      // Do something with the variable.
      printf("variable: %s\n", variable);

      // Get the next variable
      variable = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }

   // Do something with the value.
   printf("value: %s\n", value);
}

// Function to parse the "STATIC*:values" lines.
void parseLine2(char* line)
{
   char* staticString = strtok(line, ":");
   char* values = strtok(NULL, ":");
   char* value = strtok(values, " ");

   // Do something with the static string.
   printf("staticString: %s\n", staticString);

   while ( value != NULL )
   {
      // Do something with the value
      printf("value: %s\n", value);

      // Get the next value
      value = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}

int main()
{
   char line[100];

   strcpy(line, "Variable:200");
   parseLine1(line);

   strcpy(line, "Variable1:Joe");
   parseLine1(line);

   strcpy(line, "Variable0 Variable1:10.5");
   parseLine1(line);

   strcpy(line, "Variable0 Variable1 Variable2:-59.7");
   parseLine1(line);

   strcpy(line, "STATIC*:10 20 30 40");
   parseLine2(line);

   return 0;
}
```